# Menu de opções com setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma `listview`, e com `setOnItemClickListener` e/ou `setOnItemLongClickListener` faço a exclusão do registro.

Gostaria de saber como fazer para abrir uma `janela` (tipo um modal, que abre a janelinha e ofusca o fundo) com `opções`, por ex.: confirmar / cancelar.

Teria que criar uma nova activity e passar os valores para ela ?!
E para ficar somente uma janelinha com o fundo "escuro" como vemos em vários apps ?

Se tiverem artigos, tutoriais, etc podem enviar que gosto de ver todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html?hl=pt-br#AlertDialog). Ex:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SuaClasse.this);
 builder.setTitle("Excluir");
 builder.setMessage("Deseja excluir o registro?");
 builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // faz a exclusão
        }
     });
 builder.setNegativeButton("Não", null); //não faz nada
 builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
 builder.show();
```

A classe `Builder` é responsável pela criação e configuração das `AlertDialogs`.

Exemplo final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não preciso passar nenhum valor então !? Seria porque ele executa dentro do método !?

Comment: Isso, basta utilizá-lo dentro do seu método de exclusão, a única coisa que você irá precisar para excluir é o índice do item clicado. Talvez você tenha que declarar o índice do item clicado como `final` para poder acessá-lo dentro do OnClickListener do seu AlertDialog, mas isso depende da sua implementação

Comment: Funcionou certinho, só faltou um pedacinho na parte: `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);` Obrigado Zulian ! Abraço !